# Node encrypt with public certificate

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, encryption

I am trying to do the equivalent of the php [seal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php) function.
What I have is a string to encrypt, a public key and a randomly generated secret key, and I have to encode the string using the 'rs4' algorithm.

So far I managed to encode the string with the crypto functions:

```
var password = crypto.randomBytes(128);
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('rc4', password);
var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','base64');
crypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

But somehow, I need to include in the encryption the public x509 certificate.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using just one public key? If so, trying to replicate PHP's seal function is not what you want. You're looking for simple [public key encryption](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+public+key+encryption). If you do have more than one public key the manual page you linked to in your question tells you exactly what's happening. If you can't find a function in node.js that does exactly that, you can always write your own.

Comment: Yes, I only have one public key. I will follow your advise and try node ursa. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't find any way of achieving the same encryption in node, so I just called a php cli script from node that sent the data to be encrypted, and read the stdout for the encrypted base64 result :(

Answer (score 0):

RC4 is not a public key encryption system. You're looking for (in order of preference):

- node-sodium
- RSAES-OAEP with MGF1+SHA256 and e = 65537

Also, for secret-key cryptography, don't use RC4.

Comment: According to the php documentation for opensssl_seal, it is a public key and random private key method. For decripting the data, both keys are needed, + the private key of the public key. (Similar to diffie hellman?)